# vscode remote-ssh cannot connect: "Resolver error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON"

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using the VisualStudioCode extension Remote-SSH.

Development PC is Windows and ssh-host to connect to is Ubuntu.

Executing the ssh-test in Powershell works well (no password needed), but starting "Connect to host" results in:

````
[22:02:41.776] remote-ssh@0.64.0
[22:02:41.776] win32 x64
[22:02:41.778] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+7b22686f73744e616d65223a2231302e352e362e3739222c2275736572223a226a747a227d", attempt 1
[22:02:41.778] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[22:02:41.778] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[22:02:41.779] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {}
[22:02:41.779] "remote.SSH.sshPath": undefined
[22:02:41.779] "remote.SSH.sshConfigurationFile": undefined
[22:02:41.779] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[22:02:41.779] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[22:02:41.780] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[22:02:41.780] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": true
[22:02:41.780] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[22:02:41.780] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[22:02:41.780] SSH Resolver called for host: jtz@10.5.6.79
[22:02:41.780] Setting up SSH remote "10.5.6.79"
[22:02:41.818] Resolver error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ﻿ in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at l (c:\Users\jtz\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.64.0\out\extension.js:1:285459)
    at async Object.t.getProductInfo (c:\Users\jtz\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.64.0\out\extension.js:1:285517)
    at async c:\Users\jtz\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.64.0\out\extension.js:1:309806
    at async I (c:\Users\jtz\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.64.0\out\extension.js:1:309770)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\jtz\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.64.0\out\extension.js:1:315001)
    at async c:\Users\jtz\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.64.0\out\extension.js:127:110431
[22:02:41.881] TELEMETRY: {"eventName":"resolver","properties":{"osReleaseId":"","arch":"","askedPw":"0","askedPassphrase":"0","asked2fa":"0","askedHostKey":"0","remoteInConfigFile":"0","gotUnrecognizedPrompt":"0","dynamicForwarding":"1","localServer":"0","didLocalDownload":"0","installUnpackCode":"0","outcome":"failure","reason":"Unknown","exitCodeLabel":""},"measures":{"resolveAttempts":1,"timing.totalResolveTime":33}}
[22:02:41.885] ------```

Any idea welcome :-) Thanks
````

Answer (score 0):

Re-Installation of a newer version of vscode helps.